# Retrieve data using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to get data (Name , Email , Password) from user and then save them using  SharedPreferences . In second Activity I want to retrieve the data (only Email and Password) and then set them in editText. Here is my code. My data is not showing and I don't know where the problem is.

My code :-

**First Activity**

```
EditText username  , userpassword , useremail ;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences ;


static final String Email = "Email";
static final String Username = "Username";
static final String Password = "Password";

  public void RegisterrButton(View view){

    username = findViewById(R.id.username_editText);
    userpassword = findViewById(R.id.pasword_editText);
    useremail = findViewById(R.id.email_editText);

    String name = username.getText().toString();
    String password = userpassword.getText().toString();
    String email  = useremail.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(Username , name);
    editor.putString(Password , password);
    editor.putString(Email,email);
    editor.commit();


    Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

**Second Activity**

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences ;

```
static final String prefrence = "prefrence";

static final String Email = "Email";
static final String Password = "Password";

EditText useremail  , userpassword ;

 public void EnterButton(View view){

        useremail = findViewById(R.id.useremail_editText);
        userpassword = findViewById(R.id.pasword_editText);


        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(prefrence , Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ;

        if(sharedPreferences.contains(Email) ){

            useremail.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(Email , ""));}


        if(sharedPreferences.contains(Password)){

            userpassword.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(Password , ""));

        }

 }
```

Comment: If your activity is not huge, can you please copy and paste the code of the entire class? or maybe at least the parts which contribute to this code i.e. Username (what is that? a variable? object?)

Comment: are you saving email and password in shared pref? not a good idea.

Comment: @Nero I update the code

Comment: Use `putExtra()` from an `Intent` object instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following code in MainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

With

```
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "prefrence";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

Use the same MY_PREFS_NAME variable to get the info in your second activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure are you are using same shared preference  name at the time of persisting and reading the values.

```
    SharedPreferences preference = context.getSharedPreferences(<SAME_PREFERENCE_NAME>,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your Function and try this:

```
   public void saveText(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(config.PREFERENCES, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(key, value);
        ed.commit();
        ed.apply();
        toast("Yatda saklandy");
    }

    public String loadText(String key) {
        SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(config.PREFERENCES, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString(key, "");
        return savedText;
    }
```

and use it:

```
saveText("name",username.getText().toString());

loadText("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity you are not initialising **sharedPreference**
To initialise do this

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(prefrence , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Consider using apply().

It writes the changes to the RAM immediately and waits and writes it to the internal storage(the actual preference file) after. Commit writes the changes synchronously and directly to the file.